# Fitting images to ButtonImage

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to fit ImageButtons to the size of its background image for different screens sizes. The images are stored inside the drawable folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, and so on).

I've been looking around, but the answers where very outdated, or they just scale images.

This is the layout that I've used, but I had to program the TableRows, so it isn't the whole thing.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MyTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/MyTableRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"></TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I've created some rows with ImageButtons (kinda like a matrix)

(you can ignore the params X and Y, as they don't affect the images).

```
/* OnCreate()...
    myTableRow = ((TableRow) findViewById(R.id.MyTableRow));
    mainTable = new TableLayout(context);
    myTableRow.addView(mainTable, screenHeight, screenWidth / 2);
    for (int y = 0; y < MAX_NUMBER; y++)
        mainTable.addView(createRow(y));
*/

private TableRow createRow(int y) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
    row.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    for (int x = 0; x < MAX_NUMBER; x++)
        row.addView(createImageButton(x, y));
    return row;
}
```

The image "myImage" has different sizes depending on the size of the screen. The size of the button should be exactly the same as the size of the image. But I'm having a hard time trying to achieve it...

```
private View createImageButton(int x, int y) {
    ImageButton button = new ImageButton(context);      
    // Adjust button size (?)
    button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(myImage.getMinimumWidth(),
             myImage.getMinimumHeight(), 1f));
        //It doesn't work at all
    button.setBackground(myImage);
    ...
    return button;
}
```

Do yo have any ideas?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Use a `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` to have Android scale the images, and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to have them adjust their bounds due to scaling.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_topleft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

button.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY)

```
private View createImageButton(int x, int y) {
    ImageButton button = new ImageButton(context);      
    // Adjust button size (?)
    button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(myImage.getMinimumWidth(),
            myImage.getMinimumHeight(), 1f));
        //It doesn't work at all
    button.setBackground(myImage);
    button.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY)
    ...
    return button;
}
```